# Import idl files into Visual Studio (C++)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, idl

I am trying to build an application using the BlackMagic DeckLink SDK. They have a folder in their package which has a bunch of .idl files. The manual says I have to inlcude the idl file. Whats the best way to include this file so I can access its code?

I've tried putting them in the source files folder next to the main class but I still get errors that they can't be accessed.

Answer (score 1):

IDL file it self can not be accessed directly.

First you have to generate associated ".c" and ".h" files. 
Then you can consume those files by including in your project.
This process of generating "c" and "h" files, you can make it as a part of your build process.

Add the IDL file to your C++ project in visual studio.
Go to properties, you will see "custom build tool".
You can build the idl from there and create the files (.c,.h) in a known location and include them.

The below link has a screenshots explanation, regarding commands to use and how to specify custom build.

https://community.rti.com/howto/how-add-idl-file-visual-studio-project

So for your project, add all your IDL files to C++ project (say IDL folder), and provide a custom build to every IDL file (as explained in above link) , and create the output "c" and "h" files in a directory (say "generated"). Then include the headers and "c" files as required, from the "generated" folder into your project.